# C#.NET connecting to host mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to connect my C# .NET website using Visual Studio to a MySQL database located with the host 123-REG.

I have put the following code snippet (edited for security) into my web.config file:

```
 < appSettings >
 < add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=XX; Database=XX; User Id=XX; Password=XX" / > 
 < /appSettings >
```

But now I don't know what I should put in my code to read and write to this database.

So what should my connection string look like?  Also, do I need to do anything for port settings?

If anyone has already been down this path, I would really welcome your help.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql for the connection string. Are you using the [MySQL .NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)? (and are you aware of the implications that it's GPL?)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not have native support for MySql Database, so yo need to install MySql Connector/Net: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-installation-windows.html)

After from UI you can set everything, and it will generate the connection string for you: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html)

[EDIT]

From http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

For Standard connection (Default port is 3306.)

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnStr" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

If you need to specifie the port:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnStr" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't need to create my own mysql database.  The host has a shared mysql database for me to use.  As this is a unique set-up, I was hoping for some sort of example of what should be included in the connection string and any other key information that I may need to know.  Is there anyone who can help at all?

Comment: It does not say you need to install MySql Database. It is a component (from MySql) which allows you to connect to a MySql databese from VS. But to answer to your question I updated my answer with two possible connectionstring.